# Is this sentence correct? Present Perfect in the future

Tags: present-perfect, future-perfect

> I was going to close my claim after I have worked for this new company for at least one month

Is this sentence grammatically correct, I'm not sure about the "have worked" part?

Answer (score 2):

"I am going to close my claim after I have worked for this new company for at least one month"
or

"I was going to close my claim after I had worked for the new company for one month"

Comment: Number two depends on when you are speaking. If at the time of speaking, you haven't yet worked for the company for two years, you can still use 'have worked'. Had worked is also correct in this context. The rule is to do with reported speech (which includes reporting our own thoughts). The rule of 'one tense back' need not to be applied if the thing being talked about is still true. viz She said it was a beautiful view. If the view is still beautiful, we can report this as, She said it is a beautiful view.